# Remove the rows which are contain same entry different two columns

Tags: r

I have a date frame like this

```
Node <- c("A","A","B","B","B","C","C")
Event <- c("Reading", "Reading", "Eating", "Eating", "Watching", "Driving", "Driving")
Next_Event <- c("Reading", "Eating", "Eating", "Watching", "Sleeping", "Driving", "Playing")
df <- data.frame(Node, Event, Next_Event)
df
```

The expected result

```
Node <- c("A","B","B","C")
Event <- c("Reading", "Eating", "Watching", "Driving")
Next_Event <- c("Eating", "Watching", "Sleeping", "Playing")
df <- data.frame(Node, Event, Next_Event)
df
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to filter your data:

```
df[as.character(df$Event) != as.character(df$Next_Event), ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `dplyr` version of the answer provided by @holzben

```
df2 <- df %>%
  filter(as.character(Event) != as.character(Next_Event))
```

df2 output:

```
  Node    Event Next_Event
1    A  Reading     Eating
2    B   Eating   Watching
3    B Watching   Sleeping
4    C  Driving    Playing
```